# Error with Bitcore-lib signing transaction

Tags: javascript, bitcoin, bitcore

I'm trying to sign the transaction, but this error occured. I'm using testnet
(I have tried to use fromWIF secret, secret via constuctor, secret like a string)

[image: Error trace]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score -1):

window.Buffer = require("buffer").Buffer;

And

node: {
Buffer: true,
},
(webpack.config.js)